# How to avoid unwanted characters in extracted table data?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract world cup group table data. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url ="http://www.uefa.com/worldcup/season=2014/standings/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')
data = [[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
head = [[th.text.encode("utf-8") for th in tr.findAll("th")] for tr in rows]
print head
for i in data:
    print str(i)
```

Everything works fine, except I get some strange characters in output:

```
[['', 'Teams', 'P', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'F', 'A', '+/-', 'Pts'], [], [], [], []]
[]
['0', '\xc2\xa0Brazil', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '\xc2\xa0Croatia', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '\xc2\xa0Mexico', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '\xc2\xa0Cameroon', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Which are the 'strange' unwanted ones?

Comment: For instance: \xc2\xa0

Comment: You encoded text to UTF-8; lists, like all containers in Python, print their contents as *representations*; text you can paste back into Python and have it recreate the same value. `\xc2\xa0` are two UTF-8 bytes that are better represented as such then as some non-ASCII character that may or may not be supported by your terminal or editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text results includes [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00a0) characters, encoded to UTF-8 as the `C2 A0` bytes.

If you wanted to remove these, *strip* the text before encoding:

```
data = [[td.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
head = [[th.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for th in tr.findAll("th")] for tr in rows]
```

The no-break space is treated as whitespace, and like regular spaces the `str.strip()` method removes these:

```
>>> '\xc2\xa0Cameroon'.decode('utf8')
u'\xa0Cameroon'
>>> '\xc2\xa0Cameroon'.decode('utf8').strip()
u'Cameroon'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]`

To  get strings use:

```
data = [[str(td.text.strip()) for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
head = [[str(th.text) for th in tr.findAll("th")] for tr in rows]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how to make it in string ( not in unicode) again?

Comment: `str(td.text.strip())`